# my url is xyz.com/songs.pgp?lang=3&movie=198, I want to show xyz.com/moviename.html

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my url is `xyz.com/songs.php?lan=3&movie=198`,

I want to show `xyz.com/moviename.html`, is it possible with .htacces..? please help me

In my .htaccess file am using -

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ songs.php?lan=$1&movie=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Its showing - `xyz.com/telugu/moviename` but i want to show `xyz.com/moviename.html`
please help me am totally new for this

Comment: So you just want it to add `.html` at the end, and remove the subfolder?

Comment: `198` is the movie name? Please provide the current URL and the intended URL.

Comment: 198 is movie id, url is xyz.com/songs.php?lan=<?php echo $_GET['language_id']; ?>&movie=<?php echo $_GET['movie_id']; ?>

Comment: or else if url is like : xyz.com/songs.php?movie=<?php echo $_GET['movie_id']; ?>, is it possible xyz.com/moviename.php or xyz.com/moviename.html..?

Answer (score 0):

In this cases you can do like the job which CMS and Frameworks do:

First redirect all requests to index.php in the .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw|xml|jpg|ajx))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

After this, all request will redirect to your index.php. for example DOMAIN/a.html and DOMAIN/a/b.html and ...

At this time $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is the address which you have requested for example /a.html and you can decide which data should show according to the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want

> xyz.com/moviename.html

then you will need to write a rule for every movie. i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^moviename.html songs.php?lan=3&movie-123
RewriteRule ^another-moviename.html songs.php?lan=4&movie-124
```

A simpler way would be to include the movie_id somewhere in the URL:

```
# Catch xyz.com/123/the-movie-title
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/.]+).html songs.php?lan=3&movie=$2
```

this way would capture all movies without the need to a specific rule for each. You can then in your code check if the ID is valid or not. You can also grab the movie title and check it matches the URL and if not do a redirect to the correct one based off the movie id.

Comment: if url is like : xyz.com/songs.php?movie=<?php echo $_GET['movie_id']; ?>, is it possible xyz.com/moviename.php or xyz.com/moviename.html..?

Comment: You are not being very clear, but I think you may have the logic reversed. If you want xyx.com/moviename.html then you are better to run all requests through index.php using .htaccess and then grab the moviename slug and map to correct movie. I will add as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments, I think you should try a different method.

Update your .htaccess to route all request through a single file (index.php).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in index.php you can do something like (please note this need to be implemented in a secure fashion, the below is a rough outline):

```
<?php

// Copy route into variable.
$route = $_GET['route'];
$slugs = array_filter(explode('/', $route));

// Check there is a slug. e.g. a-great-movie
if(count($slugs) > 0) {

   // Perform a SQL/Database query here so see if $slug[0] matches a movie.
   // Oviously do this with you database of chose and sanitise input.
   // e.g. SELECT id FROM movies WHERE slug = $slug[0]

   // Check a match was found if so load your page content.
   if($result->rowCount() > 0 ) {
       // Show page content.
   }
   else {
      // Show a 404 page?
   }


}
else {

  // Show homepage.

}
```

After doing the above you can now go to urls like:

> xyz.com/a-great-movie
>
> xyz.com/another-great-movie

Of course you can do all thing with a routing library of your choice as well.